# How to get the n-th reference of an object declared inside the same object type?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with an object that has the same object inside and this object has inside another object and so on, for exameple:

```
class SomeObject
{
    SomeObject obj;
}

var obj= new SomeObject{ };
obj.obj= new SomeObject{ };
obj.obj.obj= new SomeObject{ };
```

My question is how do I find the latest object, I could use this:

```
if(obj.obj== null)
{
    obj.obj= new SomeObject{ }; //assign it a new object
}
```

but how to do this automatically ? How to loop through all object if the respective object doesn't implements the IEnumerable interface ? And also how do I get the reference of the latest object uninitialized so I can assign it a new object without having to do:

```
obj.obj.obj.obj = new SomeObject{ };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the concept of recursion: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx) You can declare an method and make recursive calls until you find what you want.

```
static void AddObject(SomeObject currentObject, SomeObject child) {
  if(currentObject == null) return; 
  else if(currentObject.obj != null) AddObject(currentObject.obj, child);
  else currentObject.obj = child;
}
```

Comment: I thought this may be the easiest solution but I'm not friendly with recursion, if I understand correctly, it is checking currentObeject.obj if is null and if not, the method will be called again but the currentObject will be now the previous obj which was checked, this is how "increments" until reach the final allocated obj, is that right ? Thank you !

Comment: Each subsequent call gets `currentObject.obj` as parameter - I would not directly call it the previous object, but rather the child in your chain. So if your child is holding another child (`!= null`), we just continue handling down. If the current child is the last one in the chain, and thus holding no more child (`== null`), we can now safely add the new child.

Answer (score 1):

You could go the other way round and thus eliminate the long `obj.obj.obj` chains

```
// Create the last object first and then prepend others.
SomeObject root = null;
root = new SomeObject { obj = root };
root = new SomeObject { obj = root };
root = new SomeObject { obj = root };
root = new SomeObject { obj = root };
```

Or if you don't want to inverse the order of the objects, keep a reference to the last object as well

```
SomeObject head = null; // References first object
SomeObject tail = null; // References last object.

// Add object
var item = new SomeObject();
if (tail == null) { // head is null as well.
    head = item;
    tail = item;
} else {
    tail.obj = item;
    tail = item;
}
```

The result is in fact a linked list. With a few tweaks you get:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedList<T>
{
    public Node<T> Head { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Tail { get; set; }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        var node = new Node<T>{ Data = data };
        if (Tail == null) { // Head is null as well.
            Head = node;
            Tail = node;
        } else {
            Tail.Next = node;
            Tail = node;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "while" to loop into object:

```
var obj = new SomeObject{ };
obj.obj = new SomeObject{ };
obj.obj.obj = new SomeObject{ };
var loopObj = obj;
while (loopObj.obj != null){
   loopObj = loopObj.obj;
}
```

loopObj is the last obj.

Answer (score 0):

May be bay the next way:

```
var obj= new SomeObject{ };
            obj.obj= new SomeObject{ };
            obj.obj.obj= new SomeObject{ };

            var lastObject = obj;
            int i = 0;
            while (lastObject.obj != null)
            {
                i++;
                lastObject = lastObject.obj;
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("i={0}; lastObject={1}", i, lastObject);
```